# Weyl chambers under group inclusion

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, weyl-group

Let $T$ be a fixed maximal torus of a compact Lie group $G$, and let the Weyl group $W=W(G,T)$ act on $\mathfrak t$, the Lie algebra of $T$, by fixing an identification of $\mathfrak t$ and its dual.

Suppose now that $G'$ is another compact Lie group and we have homomorphic embedding $i:G \hookrightarrow G'$ such that $i(T)\subset T'$, for $T'$ a maximal torus of $G'$, with $\dim T'>\dim T$, and that  $i(Z_G)\subset Z_{G'}$, where $Z_G, Z_{G'}$ are the centers of $G$ and $G'$, respectively. So, we have a vector space inclusion ${\mathfrak t} \subset {\mathfrak t}'$, into the Lie algebra of $T'$.

**Question:** Is it true that the intersection of ${\mathfrak t}$ with a Weyl chamber for the Weyl group $W'$ of $(G',T')$ is precisely a Weyl chamber for $W$, the Weyl group of $(G,T)$ ?

If this is not always true, are there some simple conditions (such as semi-simplicity or simply-connectedness, etc) under which it becomes true?

Comment: I think this question was asked recently and the answer is negative already in the equal rank case.

Comment: Thanks! I am interested in the case $T$ is of smaller dimension than $T'$. I have edited, accordingly.

Comment: @bernardorim Bear in mind that even a semisimple Lie subalgebra of a semisimple Lie algebra does not have to have a root system which is a subsystem of the original root system. An easy example being $\mathfrak{so}_n \leq \mathfrak{sl}_n$. As a result, the Weyl chambers certainly won't line up in general. I'm not sure if it is even true if we do take our subalgebra to be given by a root subsystem.

Comment: @Callum, thanks! It seems that the condition that is needed is that of "closed subsystem": if a sum of roots is a root of the bigger root system, it has to be also in the subsystem. I'll investigate if that condition is sufficient.